# Decomposing Changes in ROA into Changes in Operating Margin and Asset Turnover via Total Factor Productivity (TFP)

Tags: financial-economics

I am currently reading a paper on the influence of hedge fund activism on plant-level productivity. In the appendix the author describes how he decomposes changes in ROA into changes in operating margin and asset turn-over. I am trying to redo the calculation explained by the author but am unable to do so.

The author is calculating the change in operating margin via a increase in TFP using the following formula:

Operating Margin = 1-1/(TFP x price change ratio)

The author calculates 26,6 percentage as the new operating margin but I cannot replicate the calculation. Any help is appreciated.

Here the part in question:

> In Appendix B, we link formally the magnitude of the change in ROA to
>   the change in raw TFP from years  tt  to  t+3t+3 . In particular, we
>   use a modified version of the decomposition in Bosch-Badia (2010), in
>   which ROA is decomposed into TFP, input and output price changes, and
>   asset turnover. Using the “DuPont decomposition” of ROA, we obtain the
>   following relation:
>
> (A2) ROA=Operating margin × Asset turnover,ROA=Operating margin ×
>   Asset turnover,  where ROA is the ratio of earnings before interests
>   and taxes (“operating profits”) to lagged total assets, operating
>   margin is the ratio of operating profits to concurrent sales, and
>   asset turnover is the ratio of sales to lagged assets and, as
>   Bosch-Badia (2010) shows, operating margin = 1–1/(TFP × price change
>   ratio). The price change ratio is the change in output price divided
>   by the change in input price. All price changes are relative to the
>   benchmark year (i.e., year  tt ). In addition, we further make the
>   following two assumptions: (i) The baseline operating margin is 24.7%
>   (see Table 2, Column (1)), and (ii) the price change ratio is equal to
>   one (i.e., input and output prices change by the same magnitude). With
>   these assumptions we can link the change in ROA to the changes in TFP
>   and in asset turnover. First, we estimate the change in TFP using the
>   specification in Table 4, Column (4). Specifically, we narrow the
>   estimation to only manufacturing firms based on Compustat SIC codes
>   and find average productivity gains of 2.6% from years  tt  to  t+3t+3
>   for plants owned by manufacturing target firms. Second, given the
>   baseline operating margin of 24.7%, the increase in TFP of 2.6%
>   translates into an expansion in operating margin by 1.9 percentage
>   points to 26.6%. Third, the magnitude of the change in ROA also
>   depends on the change in firm-level asset turnover, which is driven by
>   reductions in capital at the plants that are not sold, and by
>   divestitures and/or closures of plants. Using Compustat data, we find
>   that for manufacturing target firms asset turnover increases from 1.07
>   to 1.20 on average from years  tt  to  t+3t+3 . Taking the two changes
>   together, the implied ROA increases by 5.5 percentage points from
>   26.4% in year  tt (= 24.7% × 1.07) to 31.9% in year  t+3t+3  (= 26.6% × 1.20).

And here a [direct link](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/28/10/2723/1581066/The-Real-Effects-of-Hedge-Fund-Activism#29466391) to the paper.

Go to Appendix B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula for OM is:

$$ OM = 1 - \frac{1}{TFP\times PCR}$$

In the baseline year, you have that Operative Margin (OM) = 0.247. Further, by assumption, price change ratio (PCR) = 1. Then:

$$TFP = \frac{1}{1-OM} = \frac{1}{1-0.247}=1.328$$

Then, you are told that the TFP changed by 2.6%. Therefore, the **new** value for TFP is 1.3625 (equivalent to 1.328 $\times$ 1.026). With this new TFP, and assuming that PCR = 1, you can find the new value for OM:

$$ OM = 1 - \frac{1}{1.3625\times 1}$$
$$ OM = 1 - 0.734$$
$$ OM = 0.266$$

There you get the 26.6% result.

Comment: This number is towards the end of Column 4 in Table 4. In the row which starts with "d[t+3] – d[t]".

Comment: I appreciate it!